# Will I be able to receive my WhatsApp chat history when i change my phone

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app

I have been using a sim for two months on my iPhone and now I gave that sim to my cousin. What I am worried about is will she recieve my WhatsApp chat history when she downloads WhatsApp to her phone.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp works on the phone number, not the phone, so you need to transfer your number

From the [WhatsApp FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/28030001)

> Before you stop using a particular phone number or phone, you should migrate your WhatsApp account to the new number or new phone.
>
> For a simple way to delete your old account number and migrate your data to a new number, use our [Change Number](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971798) feature.

Comment: Thanx for your response so does it mean she will not get the option to retrieve chat history and she is using an android phone